# Updated to Xcode 13, get unique error code when trying to run SwiftUI app on iOS but not macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

When I try to build my app I receive the following error:

> Unable to find a profile type for platform iOS and purpose
> development. You may need to reinstall Xcode.

Which I promptly did, but it does not fix the issue. Neither does cleaning build folder, rebooting, restarting, etc. Anybody encountered this before?

Answer (score 19):

I fixed this by removing "Allow Multi-Platform Builds" in Build Settings.

Comment: This works for me, too, though I don't understand why. It should be okay if the target is built for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem, it was building only on simulator and not in device. This happened after I installed a new package in SPM (*SwiftLint*).

And this is what worked for me:

1. Go to target
2. Build Settings
3. In "*Build Options*", set "*Allow Multi-platforms Builds*" to "*No*"

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself. Was an issue of having 'Targeted device families' in the build settings set to iPhone, Mac, iPad. Set it to just iPhone and it works again.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem like the right answer. All the rest of have all the targeted device families set that way, and _we_ don't have this issue.

Comment: Well it works again after changing that one setting.

Comment: I understand that, and it's great you have it working, but it _should_ work even with targeting the other devices too, since it works for the rest of us that way. A workaround is great but it is not an explanation. It would be really nice to try to arrive at an explanation! Of course you've no time for that, but that's the point of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was even more rudimentary. I had selected an iOS device in the Scheme to build for, and *switching to My Mac (in the top-middle toolbar)* resolved this cryptic error.

[image]